# Flutter app login after a logout PostgresSQLException

Tags: postgresql, flutter, firebase, dart, riverpod

I'm working on a Flutter app using Riverpod for the state management and Postgres for the database. I try to do a simple thing: display a message in the home screen with the nickname of the current user. When I logout and login to check if my feature works, my user is null and my console display a PostgresSQLException :

```
PostgreSQLSeverity.error : Attempting to reopen a closed connection. Create a instance instead.
```

Any idea where I made a mistake?
My user_repository:

```
 PostgreSQLConnection connection = PostgreSQLConnection(
      '10.0.2.2', 5432, DatabaseAccess.databaseName,
      queryTimeoutInSeconds: 3600,
      timeoutInSeconds: 3600,
      username: DatabaseAccess.databaseUser,
      password: DatabaseAccess.databasePassword);

  Future<AppUser?> getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      await connection.open();
      final result = await connection.mappedResultsQuery(
        'select * from public.user where email = @emailValue',
        substitutionValues: {
          'emailValue': email,
        },
        allowReuse: true,
        timeoutInSeconds: 30,
      );

      final userFromDataBase = result[0]['user']!;
      return AppUser(
        email: userFromDataBase['email'],
        nickname: userFromDataBase['nickname'],
        role: userFromDataBase['role'],
        firstname: userFromDataBase['firstname'],
        lastname: userFromDataBase['lastname'],
      );
    } on PostgreSQLException catch(e) {
      print(ErrorHandler(message: e.toString()));
      return null;
    }
  }
```

My screen:

```
class HomeScreen extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final currentUser = ref.watch(currentUserProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      body: currentUser.when(
        data: (user) =>  _buildBody(context, user, ref),
        loading: () =>  const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        error: (error, _) => _errorBody(context, ref),
      )
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context, AppUser? user, WidgetRef ref) {
    if(user == null) {
      return _errorBody(context, ref);
    } else {
      return Center(child: Text(
          'Welcome ${user.getNickname}',
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      ));
    }
  }

  Widget _errorBody(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return const Center(child: Text(
        "Error: No user found",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.red),
    ));
  }

}
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but connecting to a database directly from the frontend is very insecure. Anyone can extract credentials from the app or inspect the packets being sent.

Comment: @PixelToast This is not the subject indeed, my project is an exercise to better understand Flutter. But I'm interested in your suggestions to make the app more secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue with the following code. It wasn't a postgres issue but a dark story about riverpod's providers.

My providers.dart :

```
final futureCurrentUserProvider = Provider<Future<AppUser?>>((ref) {
  return UserRepository().getCurrentUser(ref.watch(emailChangeProvider));
});

final currentUserProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose<AppUser?>((ref) => UserRepository().getCurrentUser(ref.watch(emailChangeProvider)));

final authChangeProvider = StreamProvider<User?>((ref) {
  return ref.read(authRepositoryProvider).authUserChange;
});

final emailChangeProvider = Provider<String?>((ref) {
  return ref.watch(authChangeProvider).value?.email;
});
```